# How to call a ModelBuilder in ArcGIS from a python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder

I want to execute a ModelBuilder from a python script. The ModelBuilder needs two arguments. The model names is m1 and alias mytools.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# man2.py
# Created on: 2017-11-17 09:06:23.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("L:/EPEL/Opérations/MAJ/BgrSigeqRol/4_CompleterTrx/Procedure/Tache9a/AdressesQuébecProductionV3.tbx")


# Local variables:
cf = "C:\\temp\\\database.MDB\\keyfinal"
TEMPO = "C:\\temp\\\database.MDB\\TEMPO"

arcpy.gp.toolbox = "C:\\temp\\\database.MDB\\tool.tbx";


arcpy.gp.m1_mytools(cf, TEMPO)
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is some example code I show in our training material, this shows how to call a model from a python script:

```
import arcpy

# Import custom toolbox
arcpy.ImportToolbox("c:/tools/My_Analysis_Tools.tbx")

try:
    # Run tool in the custom toolbox.  The tool is identified by
    # the tool name and the toolbox alias.
    arcpy.GetPoints_myanalysis("c:/data/forest.shp")
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

`GetPoints` is the model, `myanalysis` is toolbox alias and this model takes as input 1 parameter a featureclass.